# Runtime Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object” in CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Tags: excel, vba

Hello am getting this error while executing the following code

```
Sub TableExample()


    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String

    strURL = "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html"


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
         '.Visible = True
        .navigate strURL
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Set doc = IE.document
        GetAllTables doc

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

The error is getting in this line

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

If I change it to

```
With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
```

I am using 64bit Windows 7 and office 2010 version

then what should be the code can anyone guide me on this please?

Comment: Did you try any of the advice in the answers to the other Runtime Error 429 questions?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=runtime+error+429  Basically, it might be hard to diagnose which dll isn't working without you trying a few things.

Comment: @RichardMorgan thanks for replying...yeah I have almost tried all the answers but with no luck..that is why am planning to change the code a li'l bit...so trying to use with CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")...can you please help me on this

Comment: try to compile with x86 and see if you have the same problem

Comment: @FelicePollano...  yes when I compile it with x86 it works...so whats wrong with 64bit?how to resolve it?

Comment: can anyone help me on this problem please?